# MPAndroidChart - all pieces of the pie chart are the same colour

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroidChart (https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library to generate pie chart. I followed multiple tutorials including the wiki page, but when I create my pie chart all of the pieces are the same color. Any idea how can I solve this ?

Code:

```
PieChart mChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.piechart);

List<PieEntry> pieChartEntries = new ArrayList<>();

pieChartEntries.add(new PieEntry(18.5f, "Green"));
pieChartEntries.add(new PieEntry(26.7f, "Yellow"));
pieChartEntries.add(new PieEntry(24.0f, "Red"));
pieChartEntries.add(new PieEntry(30.8f, "Blue"));

PieDataSet set = new PieDataSet(pieChartEntries, "Emotion Results");
PieData data = new PieData(set);
mChart.setData(data);
set.setColors(R.color.pieColour1,R.color.pieColour2,R.color.pieColour3,R.color.pieColour4,R.color.pieColour5,R.color.pieColour6,R.color.pieColour7,R.color.pieColour8);
mChart.invalidate();
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation says:

> When adding some additional styling, the resulting PieChart with the
>   data used above could look similar to this

These are not the real colors, but oly the labels for the colors:

```
pieChartEntries.add(new PieEntry(18.5f, "Green"));
pieChartEntries.add(new PieEntry(26.7f, "Yellow"));
pieChartEntries.add(new PieEntry(24.0f, "Red"));
pieChartEntries.add(new PieEntry(30.8f, "Blue"));
```

To add colors to the PieChart you use:

```
set.setColors(new int[]{Color.parseColor("#FF32DA64"),
                    Color.parseColor("#FF32DAD4"),
                    Color.parseColor("#FFB853F2"),
                    Color.parseColor("#FFF2ED53")});
```

or you can use one of the templates:

```
set.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
```

**EDIT:**

I just saw you're using the colors from the resources, if you inspect the `setColors` method you should see this:

> If you are using colors from the resources,make sure that the colors
>   are already prepared (by calling getResources().getColor(...))

So in your case you need to resolve the resources into `Color` objects before adding them to the `set`.

Comment: Yes the "edit" resolved my problem. I did  set.setColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.pieColour1), getResources().getColor(R.color.pieColour2)...) and this fixed it. Thanks Levi

Comment: glad it helped :)